# Using Orbeon autocomplete field for LDAP users

Tags: forms, orbeon, xforms, formbuilder

We need to fill the Orbeon autocomplete field with information about LDAP names so that the Orbeon user can select an assignee via the autocomplete field. Since we are currently using the community version, we can only specify an URI for the Data. 
I think this is a very common usecase to use the Orbeon autocomplete field for selecting LDAP names. Therefore the question how to achieve this with a single URI?

Thanks and best regards
Ben

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with LDAP, but could you create a web service that returns the list of LDAP names?

Comment: Since this is a common use case, I hoped that there is an easier approach for achieving this

Comment: You're right, but still... It's LDAP which is lacking HTTP interface. I don't think there's such embedded feature in Orbeon. With quite same need, we implemented the LDAP web service ourselves. A pity, in my opinion, should have been embedded in our LDAP server, as exist-db does for exemple.

Comment: I wrote a simple servlet to make the LDAP call. The problem is that I do not succeed in getting the data sent from the autocomplete-field to my servlet.Tried with request.getParameter and with request.getInputStream. No success. In wireshark, I see that data is tranmitted I use the following XForm build with FormBuilder: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9uw8f4ovvpku33i/autocomplete.xml?dl=0